# How does a controller in ruby on rails get id by using params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on creating a basic blog using ruby on rails. I am new to it. I have two controllers named category and post_controller. Both have a show function as shown:

for category controller:

```
Category.find(params[:id])
```

for post_controller

```
Post.find(params[:id])
```

When I enter the url

```
"localhost:3000/post_controller/2
```

It displays the posts with id 2.
But when I do the same thing for the category controller:

```
"localhost:3000/categories/2
```

It shows an error saying

```
No route matches [GET] "/categories/1"
Rails.root: /home/root/myFirstBlog
```

And yes ofcourse, I have an element in my categories database with id 2.
However when I use this url:

```
"localhost:3000/categories/show?id=2
```

It works obviously but what is the difference between the two controllers even though they have identical code.

P.S. I am confused as to what information will be relevant so please let me know in the comments. I will edit my question as required.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'categories/index'
  get 'categories'=>'categories#index'
  get 'categories/edit'
  get 'categories/new'
  get 'home/index'
  get 'post_controller/edit'
  get 'post_controller/index'
  get 'categories/edit'
  get 'categories/index'
  get 'categories/new'
  get 'categories/show'
  resources :category
  resources :post_controller
  root 'post_controller#index'
end
```

Comment: Can you past your routes file.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar I did. Please check it out.

Comment: May be you dont have categories with id=1 in the first place. try the same url that got blown away with id 2 instead of 1

Comment: place `resources :category` at the top

Comment: try `resources :categories` and remove all routes `get 'categories/xxx'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: The `resources :thing` should be pluralised

`resources :things` adds these [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

So no need for all the `get 'categories/*'` in your routes file.

Im not sure what `post_controller` is either. Should probably be renamed to. `resources :posts`

These things are probably why you are seeing inconsistencies. Without delving into it too deep its hard to say exactly whats going on.

Your routes file should look something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :category # handles actions for all categories CRUD
  resources :posts  # handles actions for all posts CRUD
  root 'post_controller#index' #root view. i.e. "/"
end
```

Comment: I figured that out. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misspelled the the controller in the URL. If your controller is categories localhost:3000/categories/2 should work.